# Spring Security 5 OAuth2 select a client programmatically

Tags: spring, security, oauth-2.0

I have an application with Spring Security 5 OAuth2 support. I have a number of OAuth2 clients to select from. I would like to execute programatic logic and, based on the incoming request, to select the target client. Now I got it to work using a custom login page and executing the logic in this custom page's controller.

In my configuration:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    logger.info("SecurityConfig.filterChain(): Entry ...");

    http.authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests -> {

        try {
            
            authorizeRequests.antMatchers("/oauth2/custom-login-page").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().
                oauth2Login().loginPage("/oauth2/custom-login-page");
        }
        catch (Exception exception) {
            
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    return http.build();
}
```

In the controller:

```
@GetMapping("/oauth2/custom-login-page")
public String getCustomLoginPage(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, HttpSession httpSession, Model model) throws Exception {


     String targetClientRegistrationID = null;

     // Custom logic to pick registrationId

     ...

     return "redirect:/oauth2/authorization/" + targetClientRegistrationID;
```

}

I would like to confirm that this is the right way to do it. If not, what would be the right/alternative way(s) to wire in such selection logic.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify multiple oauth2 providers in the config (fe: `application.yml`) file and it should be handled by the framework:

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration: 
          <custom-oauth-name>: 
            client-id: <client-id>
            client-secret: <secret>
        provider:
          <custom-oauth-name>:
            issuer-uri: https://accounts.google.com
```

More you can read here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-openid-connect#discovery